# Vertical Scrolling data entry screen in Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, vertical-scrolling

I have a data entry screen in the app. I'm able to add textfields and controls to the view, I want to add more textfields to the screen so that user can scroll down and fill the fields.

How do I add vertical scroll to a view in Xamarin IOS

Comment: are you creating the view in designer or code?

Answer (score 1):

You can add ScrollView and add all you controlls there, then on ViewDidLoad you need to set ContentSize of ScrollView and also disable horizontal scroll.